# VBA Excel: IF then Statements running loops

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA but reading books to improve.  At the moment, I am taking columns from column "A" and using them as identifiers to run a IF ELSEIF statement in another column.

Basically in `range(A1:A3)` the value "ERIC" will exist in each cell [A1 = ERIC, A2 = ERIC...] and in `range(B1:B3)` will be three different integer values [B1 = 2, B2 = 9...].  I need to find the Greater of those integers for range "ERIC" and put the Greatest value for range "ERIC" in cell(C1).

Then repeat the process in `range(A4:A6)` for value "Sally" which correlates to integer range(B4:B6)  [B4 = 1, B5 = 4...] . The greatest value would then go into cell(C4)  I have about 40 names.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: so what have you tried till now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do as you ask. It makes the assumptions that you're on `Sheet 1`, your names are in `Column A`, values in `Column B`.

```
         Public Sub FindNameAndGreatestValue()
    Dim nameColumnRowCount As Integer
    Dim nameColumn As Integer
    Dim valueColumn As Integer
    Dim outputColumn As Integer
    Dim currentName As String

    nameColumnRowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    currentName = ""
    nameColumn = 1     '1 = A - change this to column that has names
    valueColumn = 4    '4 = D - change this to the column that has values
    outputColumn = 5   '5 = E - change this to column that should contain output
    Dim currentLargestForName As Integer
    Dim currentNameStartRow As Integer
    currentLargestForName = -999
    currentName = Cells(1, nameColumn).Value
    currentNameStartRow = 1

    Dim currentRow As Integer
    For currentRow = nameColumn To nameColumnRowCount + 1
        'if last known name is the same as the current row's name
        If StrComp(currentName, Cells(currentRow, nameColumn).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            'if current rows number is larger than the last known largest number
            If currentLargestForName < CInt(Cells(currentRow, valueColumn).Value) Then
                currentLargestForName = CInt(Cells(currentRow, valueColumn).Value)
            End If
        Else
            'drop into here if the names no longer match, meaning a new name was found.
            'output the largest known number from the previous name into the first row of that name
            Cells(currentNameStartRow, outputColumn).Value = currentLargestForName
            currentNameStartRow = currentRow    'save the row this new name starts at for number output later
            currentLargestForName = CInt(Cells(currentRow, valueColumn).Value)
            currentName = Cells(currentRow, nameColumn).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Comment: I think you should submit an answer then so we can all learn ;)

Comment: hey I gave you a +1! It'd take me ages to write an array forula to do what your code does :)

Comment: Thanks [especially for the comments in the code, helps to follow your logic], this code works very well except for one small issue...  All the names/numbers will process except for the last one. I can't figure out why it wont work, not matter what the namecount is.

Comment: Oops - I apologize, that was my fault. I've made a change to the code by adding `+ 1` to the line `For currentRow = nameColumn to nameColumnRowCount`. It should work now.

Comment: Glad to help. If you're curious, the reason that worked is because we needed to go one past the last used row (e.g. row 14) in order to set off the conditional statement where the names no longer match, which then outputs the largest number as expected. Best of luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: since were on the topic of curousity, what if column B was actually C or D? I've been playing with the code a little but haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: The `value` column in my code is `nameColumn + 1`. By itself, `nameColumn` is equal to `1` which represents column `A`. So `nameColumn + 1` equals 2, which represents column `B`. If you want the `value` column to be in another column, like `D`, then you would have to find and replace `nameColumn + 1` with `nameColumn + 3` throughout the code, which appears to be in 3 different spots. The cleaner approach is to create a **variable** named `valueColumn` and set it to the appropriate column value (e.g. D = 4). Then replace `nameColumn + 1` with `valueColumn`. It makes future changes easier

Comment: I've made an edit to the answer to demonstrate what I mean. You'll now notice 3 variables at the top of the code: `nameColumn`, `valueColumn` and `outputColumn`. Set these variables to the appropriate column.

Comment: Hi again, I added some code `ElseIf currentLargestForName = CInt(Cells(currentRow, valueColumn).Value) Then currentLargestForName = "two are the same"`to indicate if two of the integers in column B are the same but also want to indicate if three of the intergers are the same. I can't seem to get it to work if three integers in column B are the same to work. Thoughts?